# How to handle dropdown data and fetched English data when my user choose another language?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, localization, internationalization, i18next

I am work on adding more than one language to my Application using i18n-js. My concern is how to handle static data like currency, level of experience, ...etc which is written in English to use it by my dropdown list when user select one item from dropdown it should be sent to the back end in English format and how to handle fetched data with English format if user have chosen another language.

Is it regular to save same type of data to backend in different languages.

I have tried to add all my static data in my language files and when user choose a specific language it would fetch it's corresponded data from language file.

Here is a code sample from language files:

**English file**

```
export default en = {
     educationDropDownList: [
        {
            label: `Secondary School`,
            value: `Secondary School`
        },
        {
            label: `Deploma`,
            value: `Deploma`
        },
        {
            label: `Bachelor's degree`,
            value: `Bachelor's degree`
        },
        {
            label: `Master's degree`,
            value: `Master's degree`
        },
        {
            label: `Doctoral degree`,
            value: `Doctoral degree`,
        }

    ]
}
```

**Arabic file**

```
export default ar = {
    educationDropDownList: [
        {
            label: `مدرسة ثانوية`,
            value: `مدرسة ثانوية`
        },
        {
            label: `شهادة دبلوم`,
            value: `شهادة دبلوم`
        },
        {
            label: `درجة البكالوريوس`,
            value: `درجة البكالوريوس`
        },
        {
            label: `درجة الماجيستير`,
            value: `درجة الماجيستير`
        },
        {
            label: `درجة الدكتوراه`,
            value: `درجة الدكتوراه`,
        }

    ]
}
```

I have two cases here. first, how to handle sending selected data to Backend with different language format and how to receive that selected data and view it with proper language format.

Comment: Mostly you will be saving the value to backend in english itself, so for your dropdown there will be a key based on the key retrieved from the backend service you can show the text based on user choice. So in your case label will act as a key and the displayText will be the value that will be seen by the user

Answer (score 3):

Using different languages makes things confusing. Keep to the one you developing with. In other words, i18n pulls the language from language files that is linked to a key.
e.g (https://i18njs.com/#language_files) :

```
{
  "values":{
    "Yes": "はい",
    "No": "いいえ",
    "Ok": "Ok",
    "Cancel": "キャンセル"
  }
}
```

Regardless of what the language is the software runs on a key and ignores the values. When displaying the value on the browser the dropdown displays whatever the key contains as a value e.g: i18n("Yes") would give you はい if the language was set as Japanese.

Populate your Arabic and English collections dynamically generically such as example:

```
export default genericdropdown = {
    educationDropDownList: [
        {
            label: i18n("Yes"),
            value: "Yes"
        },
        {
            label: i18n("No"),
            value: "No"
        }, ...
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

your translation files:

```js
English
{ 
  "yes":"Yes"
  }


Arabic  

  {
  "yes":"نعم"
  }
```

and then in your dropdown, you only change label's value based on the chosen language. this means that a user who selected Arabic language, will see arabic translation of the dropdown option, but you will send the value which is in english to your backend.

```
export default genericdropdown = {
educationDropDownList: [
    {
        label: i18n.t("yes"),
        value: "Yes"
    },
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-il8n package for translation just do this:

This is your dropdown component file.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import il8n from "./i18n.js";
import { withNamespaces } from "react-i18next";

const LanguageDropdown = ({ t, props }) => {
  const changeLanguage = (language) => {
    il8n.changeLanguage(language);
  };

  return (
    <li className="nav-item d-none d-md-block">
      <a className="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <div className="customize-input">
          <select
            className="custom-select form-control bg-white custom-radius custom-shadow border-0"
            onChange={(e) => changeLanguage(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="">{t("Choose Language")}....</option>
            <option value="en">{t("English")}</option>
            <option value="fe">{t("French")}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  );
};

export default withNamespaces()(LanguageDropdown);
```